# Merge dataframe rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset, pandas-groupby

Hi I have a dataset like this:

| ID | Gender | Group | Biomarker | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Male | Test | CA125 | X1 |
| 001 | Male | Test | CEA | X2 |
| 001 | Male | Test | AFP | X3 |
| 002 | Female | Control | CA125 | X4 |
| 002 | Female | Control | CEA | X5 |
| 002 | Female | Control | AFP | X6 |

I want to merge all rows with the same id into a single row and change the column names to the biomarkers for example:

| ID | Gender | Group | CA125 | CEA | AFP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Male | Test | X1 | X2 | X3 |
| 002 | Female | Control | X4 | X5 | X6 |

Some IDs might not have some of the biomarkers: I want them to have missing data in the final table***
Some IDs might have several values for a biomarker: I want them to have the minimum of the values

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DataFrame.pivot()` method

```
piv = df.pivot(index=['ID', 'Gender', 'Group'], 
               columns='Biomarker', 
               values='Value')\
               .reset_index()
```

Comment: It gives error -->  ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Comment: Please check whether you have more than one row with the same values of ID, Gender and Group and check if it would make sense to maintain all these rows or if only one should be kept.